# Javascript update a array data depending on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a simple array and I want to update this array with the value `order:"asc"` and want to delete all other `order` key only if `type == "user"` and `key == "country"`

```
const items = [
    {
        type: "user",
        values: [
            {order:"asc", key:"first_name"},
            {key:"last_name"},
            {key:"address"},
            {key:"country"},
        ]
    },
]
```

My expected result is

```
const items = [
    {
        type: "user",
        values: [
            {key:"first_name"},
            {key:"last_name"},
            {key:"address"},
            {order:"asc", key:"country"},
        ]
    },
]
```

I'm able to do this with `map` inside `map`. Is it possible without looping twice?

```
items.map(
    x => { if (x.type == "user") {
        x.values = x.values.map(y => {
            if (y.key.includes("country")) {
                y.order = "asc"
            } else if (JSON.stringify(x.values).includes("country")) {
                delete y.order
            }
            return y
        })
    }
    return [x]
});
```

Comment: The only actual [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) in your question is the result of `JSON.stringify(x.values)` - and that call is not necessary and just adds a potential source for unwanted behavior.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this without a double loop. Because you have two independent arrays. And each array has to have a loop. Map, filter, foreEach all have a loop under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do that only with double loop. I write this script but it similar to yours.

```js
var newItems = items.map(el => {
  if(el.type === "user"){
    el.values = el.values.map(value => {
      if(value.key === "country"){
        value["order"] = "asc"
      }else if(value["order"] != undefined){
        delete value["order"]
      }
      return value
    })
    return el
  }
})
```

Comment: It works if I have `{key:"country"},`. If I don't have this `country` key, then it removes the `order:asc` from the item `{order:"asc", key:"first_name"},`. I don't want to delete `order:"asc"`, if the values does not contains `country`.

Answer (score 1):

**Logic**

- Loop through `items` array.
- Find nodes with `type` `"type"`
- From that nodes loop through `values` array.
- Clear `"order"` of nodes where key is not `"country"`
- Add `"order"` as `"asc"` where key is `"country"`

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const items = [
  {
    type: "user",
    values: [
      { order: "asc", key: "first_name" },
      { key: "last_name" },
      { key: "address" },
      { key: "country" },
    ]
  },
];

items.filter(item => item.type === "user").forEach(item => {
  item.values.filter(value => value.order === "asc").forEach(value => value.order && value.key !== "country" ? delete value.order : {});
  item.values.filter(value => value.key === "country").forEach(value => value.order = "asc");
});

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
items.filter(itm => itm.type == "user")
  .map(u => {u.values.map(v => {
      delete v.order
      if (u.values.key == "country")
        u.values.order = "asc"    
    })
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to delete `order:"asc"` if there is no `country` in the `values` array then instead of `JSON.stringify(x.values).includes("country")` upon every object in `values` you could use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and then only loop and delete if there is an object with `key:"country"`:

```js
const items = [ { type: "user", values: [ {order:"asc", key:"first_name"}, {key:"last_name"}, {key:"address"}, {key:"country"}, ] }, ]

const result = items.map(obj => {
  if (obj.type === 'user') {
    const country = obj.values.find(o => o.key === 'country')

    if (country) {
      obj.values.forEach(value => delete value.order)
      country.order = 'asc'
    }
    
  }
  return obj
})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```